# How do I make a keyword search with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to create a keyword search on my website.

I have a search bar and type into it a keyword such as angry. My url will now be **www.website.com/?s=angry**

How do I go do the mysql search query for the keyword on my VARCHAR fields?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) or [Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-search.html)*

- Full-text indexes can be used only MyISAM (MySQL 5.5 and before)
- Full-text indexes can be used only MyISAM and InnoDB (MySQL 5.6 )

Comment: innodb supports fulltext as of mysql 5.6.4

Comment: @aykut so at the moment im using this

 $q = "SELECT * from post WHERE post_type like '%".$_GET['s']."%'";

How would I change this to a fulltext search

Comment: Here is a tutorial about full text search in PHP http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` in your SQL Statement:

```
$search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['s']);
$query = "select column from table where varchar_column like '%$search%'";
```

This will find all occurances of your search string in your VARCHAR column.

Edits: Added code to help prevent SQL Injection. Obviously you should always protect your queries from injection when applying them to a production envionment.

Comment: $q = "SELECT * from ______ WHERE ______ like '%".$_GET['s']."%'"; cleaned it up for you but it works. Cheers.

Comment: @MarcB Added a quick injection prevention step, as well as a disclaimer.

Comment: actually i take that back haha. is it possible to get a better search for example if you type in **an** the columns with angry will come into the search. How would I change it to a fullword search

Comment: You could add a space before and after the search term, something like `where varchar_column like '% an %'. Which would require a space before and after the term, and thus a full word.

Answer (score 0):

Well first you must get the search string from the url. This can be done in php with the $_GET global. The key represents the "s=" part of the url.

```
$search = $_GET['s'];
```

Then you need to make a MYSQL query to search your fields

```
SELECT * (or whatever column you need) FROM (table) WHERE (column) LIKE '%($search)%'
```

I would recommend using a PDO prepared statement to execute the query so the $search variable is automatically escaped.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
$search = $_GET['s'];   //clean this up to avoid sql injection
```

MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE field1 LIKE '%search%' OR
      field2 LIKE '%search%' OR
      ...
      fieldn LIKE '%search%'
```

where `search` should be replaced with what user entered

Comment: @MarcB Notice I didn't use the variable in the MySQL? It's not the continuation of the PHP code, I was just showing the concept. That is why I separated them into sections, not assuming how the OP might want to put them together